# How to set dependency properties, AddOwner, in a simple custom control for FormattedText in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls, dependency-properties, formatted-text

I *know* this topic has been covered many times. I think I've studied most of them. But I can't seem to make this work with AddOwner(). I'm a newbie.

I wish to make a very *simple* custom control to display a FormattedText. Even though the dependency properties ***are*** called from the XAML, they are ***not*** being set and their new settings are ***not*** available in the constructor.

What am I doing wrong? (Maybe the question should be how to correctly use AddOwner() ? ).

Thank you for any help.

```
XAML:
<i:CustomTextBlock Grid.Row="0"  x:Name="tbc"
               Text="{Binding Text}" 
               FontSize="{Binding FontSize}" 
               FontStyle="Italic" 
               Foreground="{Binding Color}" 
               FontFamily="Segoe Script" />

C#:

   public class CustomTextBlock : FrameworkElement
   {
    public CustomTextBlock() 
    {
        FontWeight fontweight = FontWeights.Normal;
        FontStretch fontstretch = FontStretches.Normal;
        FlowDirection flowdirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;

        Typeface typeface = new Typeface(
         FontFamily,
         FontStyle,
         fontweight,
         fontstretch);

        FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(
             Text,
             System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture,
             flowdirection,
             typeface,
             FontSize,
             Foreground);
    }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = 
        TextBlock.TextProperty.AddOwner(typeof(CustomTextBlock));

       public String Text
    {
        get { return (String)this.GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

       public static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty =
        TextBlock.FontSizeProperty.AddOwner(typeof(CustomTextBlock));

    public Double FontSize
    {
        get { return (Double)this.GetValue(FontSizeProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontStyleProperty =
        TextBlock.FontStyleProperty.AddOwner(typeof(CustomTextBlock));

    public FontStyle FontStyle
    {
        get { return (FontStyle)this.GetValue(FontStyleProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(FontStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ForegroundProperty =
        TextBlock.ForegroundProperty.AddOwner(typeof(CustomTextBlock));

    public Brush Foreground
    {
        get { return (Brush)this.GetValue(ForegroundProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ForegroundProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontFamilyProperty =
        TextBlock.FontFamilyProperty.AddOwner(typeof(CustomTextBlock));

    public FontFamily FontFamily
    {
        get { return (FontFamily)this.GetValue(FontFamilyProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(FontFamilyProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
     }

}
```

Comment: What template are you using?

Comment: @Pragmateek There is no template in a control that is directly derived from FrameworkElement.

Comment: @Clemens Exact but the title is about custom control so I've extrapolated there is an error in the design of the class. IMHO it should inherit from `Control`. I don't see any point in defining it this way...

Comment: @Clemens Ah and by the way have you an example of possible issue when setting the `DataContext` of the root element in a UC? (Sorry for asking here but SO has still not implemented private messaging by design, I'll delete it after). Thanks

Comment: @Pragmateek Read the question. OP is deriving a control directly from FrameworkElement, and providing visual output by means of an overridden OnRender method. Perfectly valid.

Comment: @Clemens Valid for sure but strange for sure too. I've only seen this kind of stuff for a custom shape that looked like a music note.

Comment: @Clemens I guess there is more code than that in the real OP project...

Comment: All comments help me better understand these concepts. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with AddOwner, but the properties are set *after* the constructor is called. You have to use their values in the overridden OnRender method, and you may just drop the entire constructor:

```
public class CustomTextBlock : FrameworkElement
{
    // property declarations
    ...

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        var typeface = new Typeface(
            FontFamily,
            FontStyle,
            FontWeights.Normal,
            FontStretches.Normal);

        var formattedText = new FormattedText(
            Text,
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture,
            FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            typeface,
            FontSize,
            Foreground);

        drawingContext.DrawText(formattedText, new Point());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Works great! I am slowly learning these new concepts. Great mentoring!

Comment: One small additional question. I am using a StackPanel to vertically align the CustomTextBlock. All the CustomTextBlocks are writing over each other, so how to get new Point()???

Comment: Currently you have no code that returns the actual size of the derived FrameworkElement. I'd suggest to also override MeasureOverride, create the same FormattedText object and returns its size. As an optimization you may later create the FormattedText only when one of the related properties (Text, Font*, etc.) changes. You'd keep the FormattedText object and use it in OnRender and MeasureOverride. You would have to add PropertyChanged callbacks by passing dependency property metadata to AddOwner.

Comment: `new Point()` just means `new Point(0, 0)`. The value is relative to the element's upper left corner.

Comment: Thanks. I will try. It maybe a long day :)